# Edit character length of row names in R

Tags: r

I am working on Bioinformatics recently. I have to edit row.names for my variable. Here is the situation for me:

I have clinical data and gene expression values downloaded from Cancer Genome Atlas. I have to match row names but in clinical data I have row names like this  "TCGA-6D-AA2E". But in gene expressions row names like "TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A-11R-A38B-07".
Normally I used "match" command to match row names but the character lengths are not same. So my question is "Is there easy way to edit character length for row names?"

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? do you want to reduce the length ? do you want to select some characters ? Can you be more explicit please ?

Comment: I want to select first twelve character from this row name "TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A-11R-A38B-07"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` function instead:

```
gene.names <- c("TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A-11R-A38B-07", "TCGC-6D-AA2E-01A-11R-A38B-07", "TAGA-6D-AA2E-01A-11R-07", "TCGA-6D-AA2E-A38B-07")

pick <-  "TCGA-6D-AA2E"

grep(pick, gene.names)
# [1] 1 4
```

Edit based on the comment: Use `substr` to pick 12 first characters:

```
substr(gene.names, 0,12)
#[1] "TCGA-6D-AA2E" "TCGC-6D-AA2E" "TAGA-6D-AA2E" "TCGA-6D-AA2E"
```

Comment: Thank you Mikko! substr exactly what I need!